# Merge every single line from txt 1 with every single line from txt 2 and save as txt 3

Tags: text-processing

txt 1:

```
abc
trt
prc    etc
```

txt 2:

```
1
2
3     etc
```

txt 3:

```
abc1
abc2
abc3  
trt1
trt2
trt3
prc1
prc2
prc3   etc
```

Comment: Not doing your homework without you even asking a question of your own (this is a question and answer site) and without you showing an attempt of your own!

Comment: also, this has been asked here before, and you've not even read through the list of "related" topics that were offered to you before you clicked on "post" on your question (see the fifth from the top), so -1 for insufficient research.

Comment: this post ?   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646109/merge-files-line-by-line?rq=1

Comment: Here are some tips: If you expect people to make an effort and answer your question, you also need to show you're making an effort. For instance, by writing a clear and detailed question inside the post. By writing examples that are easier to read and understand, and not just "sdfsdfsdf" which shows a total lack of effort from your side. By adding some thoughts about possible tools and methods. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/722691/edit) and improve your question. If you show some respect to the site, you might get respect back by an answer. Good luck.

Comment: While the [initial version of the question](/revisions/722691/1) was gibberish and likely explains the first downvotes, the current version is interesting and IMO doesn't deserve that barrage of downvotes and criticisms and is no less good than half the text-processing questions here.

Comment: Similar: [Command line tool to "cat" pairwise expansion of all rows in a file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169625)

Comment: This works. `parallel -a first_f -a second_f echo {1}{2}`.

Answer (score 0):

If the files  can fit in memory:

```
perl -e 'chomp (@a = <STDIN>); @b = <>;
         for $a (@a) {for $b (@b) {print $a,$b}}' < 'txt 1' 'txt 2'
```

Or if the Cartesian product can fit in memory, in `zsh`:

```
a=( ${(f)"$(<'txt 1')"} )
b=( ${(f)"$(<'txt 2')"} )
print -rC1 -- $^a$^b
```

(that one removes empty lines for both files)